# SSH responding poorly

Tags: server, command-line, ssh

Why do command line prompts respond poorly I am when SSH'ing into a terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by "poorly": slowly or wrongly?

Comment: slow very slow..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it slow only when connecting or during the SSH session, once connected?

You can diagnose the point at which it "stalls" during session startup by using the -v parameter. My hunch is that it's stalling when trying to resolve your computer's IP address. If you have control over the SSH server to which you're connecting, you could add

```
UseDNS no
```

to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to bypass the DNS resolving step. Optionally (and IMHO better/safer, but not always feasible), add your computer's IP address to the server's `/etc/hosts` so it resolves more quickly.

If it's slow *during* the session, that would sound like a lower-level networking problem, you can use `ping` to the server to diagnose round-trip times and see if they are OK (anything above 100-200 ms is going to start feeling sluggish for interactive use -depends on how patient you are :) ).